# How can a computer access the Internet through another?

Tags: networking, routing

Suppose there are two Linux laptop computers A and B that are close to each other in the same room. Both can connect to a home WiFi LAN, and then to the Internet.

```
A or B <-> home LAN router <-> ISP <-> the Internet
```

Can computer A connect to the Internet indirectly by computer B, while B keeps connected to the home WiFi and therefore can access the Internet? What are the steps and commands to make that happen? (Sorry, I know little about Linux networking, and will read more about that if I can get some guidance here.)

```
A <-> B <-> home LAN router <-> ISP <-> the Internet
```

Is the fact that A can be connected to the home WiFi irrelevant, if we **insist** A connect to the Internet through B?

Is it to create a LAN between B and A, with B being a router for the LAN, while B keeps connected to the home LAN?

Does computer B (or A) have to have two network interfaces?

How is the new LAN between B and A created?

- Physically, is it by connecting their Ethernet ports directly via an Ethernet cable? Can the new LAN be wireless?
- Linux-wise, what are the steps and commands to create the LAN?

How can B be made to relay internet traffic to and from A?

Comment: If you chose wireless: why would you want this? if both A and B can access the same wireless network, A inherently *must* be able to connect to your router, without help of B. And unless there's another access point involved that you don't mention, then all packets from A to B would have to go through your router (assuming that is also is responsible for your WLAN), so you only make everything worse by adding B in between A and your router.

Comment: I want this for learning purposes.

Comment: note that sharing a wifi connection via wifi might be not a great learning experience. You cannot sensibly make use of the router's DHCP, so you'd be doing things with fixed addresses that no sensible network admin would recommend. The "wifi over wifi sharing" use case is a bit contrieved, to be perfectly honest :)

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: use the built-in connection sharing tools of your Linux user desktop environment. There's different desktop environments (Gnome, KDE, …), so instructions differ a bit, but the idea and underlying architecture is the same.

Prerequisites: you'll want to make sure the `dnsmasq` package for your distro is installed. Different distros are different as you know, so I can't tell you the concrete steps for your distro, as you don't mention it. It should be fairly easy for an experienced user as yourself!

## Sharing internet through a wired connection

Click on the network icon ; go for "Edit Connection…" or similar (try right-clicking if such a field doesn't appear when left-clicking).

In the connection overview, find the "add" or "+" button, and add a new Ethernet connection. Give it a recognizable name, like "sharing the internet".

Go to the tab that says "IPv6 settings". As "Method" choose "Shared to other computers" or similar.

Go to the tab that says "IPv4 settings" and do the same.

Done. Plug in your other computer via cable.

## Sharing Internet Through a Wireless Connection

Most wifi cards do not support being an access point and a client at the same time, so for this to work, you'll need a separate network interface you can dedicate to sharing the internet with the other computer. Also note that it would be a good idea to not use the same Wifi channel, otherwise your computer will "clog" its own uplink to the router.

Click on the network icon, and click on "create new wireless network…" or similar. You're asked what you want to call this network (invent a name), an encryption method (WPA2 is fine), and a password (make it 8 characters or longer).

For a minute you'll be able to authenticate the other computer using the same password.

## The long story

What these tools do:

1. Set up the network interface (which is a lot more complicated in the wifi case, but in the end, it's just preparing the security layer in wlan and making the wifi card emit beacons, so that your other computer can connect to it)
2. Assign an address from a private network to that network interface
3. start a daemon that dynamically assigns network addresses to connected computers (using DHCP) (this is where `dnsmasq` gets used)
4. set up the nftables IP packet tools to take IP packets coming from that other computer, rewrite their header to make them look as if they come from this computer (that's NAT, network address translation), and the other way around for replies.

This is *not* the only way such a network can work. In fact, if you wanted IPv6-only access, the whole "address assignment" and "network address translation" is superfluous, and your computer could simply delegate a prefix (your ISP gives your router a whole subnet of IPv6 addresses. For example, I have a full 2⁵⁶ addresses that my ISP gives my router, and that router is free to give subranges of that to computers on its internal side to themselves delegate to other computers. That *is* a lot easier. However, few people want IPv6-only connectivity. And because global IPv4 addresses are expensive, your whole network gets only one from your ISP, and you need to unify all IPv4 devices behind that one. And so, NAT is often the only thing that reliably works on different connections, so it's the only thing these connection sharing wizards offer.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have GUI tools. I prefer commands, i.e. CLI tools

Comment: 100% same thing can be done using `nmcli` instead of the graphical tools, but of course, you would need to understand what you're doing, and you literally ruled that out in your question ;)

Comment: where did I say I don't want to understand how to do that?

Comment: I didn't mean you said that you ruled out learning, you ruled out having learned already: "Sorry, I know little about Linux networking, and will read more about that if I can get some guidance here"

Comment: kind of obviously, learning about networking theory first before asking how to do it is the way to learn how it works underneath, so I interpreted your question of learning how to *set it up*, not learning *how someone without tools but skills* would set it up.

Comment: what does that have to do with my preference for commands?

Comment: sorry, not here to argue.

Comment: Nowhere did I say that I want to rule out the concepts and theory. I just commented about the tools.

Comment: and I told you the same can be done using the CLI tool `nmcli`. Have a great day!

Comment: yes, I want to know about the steps using CLI tools including but not limited to nmcli.

Comment: hence my "the long story" explanation. I don't know what else you want – it contains the tools, it contains the words to read up on (in *italics*, even). So, go and learn!

Comment: I don't have a desktop environment. What are some popular examples of connection sharing tools?

Comment: … I literally wrote that already. `nmcli`, `dnsmasq`, `nftables`. It's already in my answer, you'll have to read it closely if you want to know my answer to your question.

Comment: "Most wifi cards do not support being an access point and a client at the same time, so for this to work, you'll need a separate network interface you can dedicate to sharing the internet with the other computer." Will an external USB wireless adapter work as "a separate network interface you can dedicate to sharing the internet with the other computer"?